# How can I make a Wicket modal window un-draggable?

Tags: java, wicket

I am using a Wicket modal window in my application. Is there any way to make it un-draggable? Any information will be very helpful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no support for this, at least out of the box. It *is* possible to prevent the user from resizing the window, but draggability is not affected by that.

Full Javadoc for `ModalWindow` in version 1.4.7 is [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket-extensions/1.4.7/wicket-extensions-1.4.7-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/ModalWindow.html).

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Lord Torgamus, the standard `ModalWindow` can not be made un-draggable.

As an alternative, however, you could use the [wiquery dialog](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/wiki/Dialog). It offers the same confiuration options as the [JQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog). Among other things, you can control draggability.