# how can we remove the draggable property from modal window in wicket

Tags: wicket, modal-window

I am new in wicket i have `modal window` which have a property of `draggable` I want to remove the draggable from the window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can anybody give the type of jquery how can i use the jquery to avoid drag property of modal-window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a jQuery script to trigger a mouseup event when the user triggers a mousedown event on the draggable area.
You have to add this in the head of the html for the modal windows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
  <head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function()
      {
        $(".w_caption").mousedown(function(){$(this).trigger("mouseup")});
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  .................
```

Make sure you also reference jQuery in the head of the modal html. (tested with jquery-1.8.3)

Comment: Modal window is draggable on page I want that it has fix position not move or drag here and there any where .....

This Jquery is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. For an alternative you might want to have a look at wiQuery (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932232/how-can-i-make-a-wicket-modal-window-un-draggable))